# Make HTTP POST request from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, cors, csp

I want to make a post request to a server, using this code:

```
({
    start : function(component, event, helper) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://site.com/service";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(json);
            }
        };
        var data = JSON.stringify({
              "evse_id": "scscrfgdfsgdfsdsfdgfd", 
              "plug_id": 1,
              "id_tag": {
                "tag_id": "test", 
                "tag_type": "UID"
              },
              "provider_id": "QTEDFF",
              "session_id": "123456789"
            }

        );
        xhr.send(data);
    }
})
```

I added `https://site.com/service` in **CSP Trusted Site Definition** and in 
**CORS Whitelist Origins** but it shows this error message:

```
Failed to load https://site.com/service: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Is it possible to invoke this method only from the Lightning Component or have I to do from an Apex Class?

Comment: you should be able to do it either way, however, considering you have sensitive info, i would suggest you do your request from the server (apex)

Comment: why, in your opinion,  I got that message?

Comment: Is the site.com/service endpoint a Salesforce API? I tried looking it up but didn't find anything. If it is, Salesforce specifically excludes calling Salesforce APIs from Lightning via Locker Service. You can test this by setting your component's API version to 39.0.

Comment: the endpoint is an external service from Salesforce. So, due to Locker Service is not possible, is it?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to an API via AJAX, the API you're calling must be CORS-enabled, and you must follow CORS rules.  This stands in contrast to an API callout that you might do via Postman or Apex, which doesn't require CORS.  The browser will enforce this.  These rules apply to all web applications, not just Salesforce Lightning Components.

Per CORS, the server you're calling has to return a header called "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" with "token" as part of the value in its response.  Otherwise you'll be blocked from submitting a header called "token" via AJAX.

The absence of an Access-Control-Allow-Headers header explicitly allowing the token header in the request suggests to me that this API probably has not addressed CORS.  The API response is probably missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as well -- which is the main requirement of CORS.

If you can't use Apex, you'll need to get the API provider on-board with enabling CORS.  You can refer them to https://enable-cors.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message -->

> Failed to load https://site.com/service: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Is basically telling you that the Server where site.com is hosted does not accept your request, or more specifically, the Token in the request header. Unless you have control over the server, you wont be able to do this request client side.

Comment: but I must include it... with postman works well

Comment: AFAIK, Postman won't be doing preflight requests. I think @glls is right, you'd need to allow `token` header in preflight request if you have access to the backend, or move the API to Apex